# Area of n-Sided planar polygon in 3D space

Tags: java, polygons

So, I have a set of n coordinates (x,y,z) for a planar n-Sided polygon. The coordinates aren't in any particular format yet as I wasn't sure what would be most suitable for the application. From this I need to extrapolate the area of the Polygon, but I have no real idea on how to accomplish this.

I thought about using Polygon Triangulation then calculating the length of each side to use in Heron's Formula for the areas of each triangle before summing them up. But I wasn't sure if there was an easier way? Let alone where to begin implementing this.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'd probably go the triangulation route. If the polygon is convex it shouldn't be too hard to get the triangulation.

Comment: Project onto 2 dimensions, then use the shoelace formula.

Comment: Have a look here for some hints: http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a triangle in 3D space is given by half the magnitude of the cross-product of the vectors of two of its sides.

```
area = |   (v1 - v0)   x   (v2 - v0)   | / 2
```

Or, element-wise:

```
       | [ (x1 - x0) ]   [ (x2 - x0) ] |
area = | [ (y1 - y0) ] x [ (y2 - y0) ] | / 2
       | [ (z1 - z0) ]   [ (z2 - z0) ] |
```

So, you can just pick one the polygon's first vertex as `[z0 y0 z0]`, and just sum this quantity over all vertices:

```
area = | sum_i   (v_(i) - v0)   x   (v_((i+1) % N  - v0)   | / 2
```

Or, element-wise:

```
       |       [ (x_(i) - x0) ]   [ (x_((i+1) % N) - x0) ] |
area = | sum_i [ (y_(i) - y0) ] x [ (y_((i+1) % N) - y0) ] | / 2
       |       [ (z_(i) - z0) ]   [ (z_((i+1) % N) - z0) ] |
```

where `sum_i` is supposed to indicate the sum over all vertices, for `i in 0..(N-1)`, and the subscription `_(i)` indicates the coordinate of the i-th vertex. `(i+1) % N` simply handles the wrapping of the polygon points (i.e. the `N-1`-th point has a line to the `0`-th point).

Note that the magnitude is taken *after* summing the cross products.

Comment: Thank you for the help, after a little thinking and doing it on paper it worked, so time to implement!

Comment: will this theory work for concave polygons?

Comment: @ImtiazShakilSiddique yes.